# Same code behaves differently as a pure function and a function, and insider another function

Tags: functions, replacement, evaluation, rule, pure-function

I have a rule-transformer that takes a list of rules (and a list `generator = {σ[z], σ[-1], σ[1]}`)

```
algebra = {σ[z] ** σ[1] :> σ[1],
 σ[z] ** σ[-1] :> -σ[-1],
 σ[1] ** σ[z] :> -σ[1],
 σ[-1] ** σ[z] :> σ[-1],
 σ[1] ** σ[1] -> 0,
 σ[-1] ** σ[-1] -> 0,
 σ[z] ** σ[z] -> Id,
 σ[1] ** σ[-1] -> 1/2 (Id + σ[z]),
 σ[-1] ** σ[1] -> 1/2 (Id - σ[z])
 }
```

and turn it into

```
{σ[z][n_] ** σ[1][n_] :> σ[1][n],
σ[z][n_] ** σ[-1][n_] :> -σ[-1][n],
σ[1][n_] ** σ[z][n_] :> -σ[1][n],
σ[-1][n_] ** σ[z][n_] :> σ[-1][n],
σ[1][n_]^2 :> 0,
σ[-1][n_]^2 :> 0,
σ[z][n_]^2 :> 1,
σ[1][n_] ** σ[-1][n_] :> 1/2 (1 + σ[z][n]),
σ[-1][n_] ** σ[1][n_] :> 1/2 (1 - σ[z][n])}
```

The transformer reads

```
Transformer = 
  Table[(#[[i]][[1]] /. {$g_ :> $g[n_] /; MemberQ[generators, $g]}) :>
      Evaluate[(#[[i]][[
         2]] /. {gg_ :> gg[n] /; MemberQ[generators, gg]})], {i, 
     Length[#]}] &;
```

I can call `Transformer[algebra]` to generate the desired list. However, if I define `Transformer` by

```
Transformer[algebra_] := 
 Table[(algebra[[i]][[
       1]] /. {$g_ :> $g[n_] /; MemberQ[generators, $g]}) :> 
    Evaluate[(algebra[[i]][[
        2]] /. {gg_ :> gg[n] /; MemberQ[generators, gg]})], {i, 
    Length[algebra]}]
```

calling `Transformer[algebra]` gives some weird output

```
{σ[z] ** σ[1] :> σ[1][
   n$], σ[z] ** σ[-1] :> -σ[-1][n$], σ[
    1] ** σ[z] :> -σ[1][n$], σ[-1] ** σ[
    z] :> σ[-1][n$], σ[1]^2 :> 0, σ[-1]^2 :> 
  0, σ[z]^2 :> 1, σ[1] ** σ[-1] :> 
  1/2 (1 + σ[z][n$]), σ[-1] ** σ[1] :> 
  1/2 (1 - σ[z][n$])}
```

Similarly, if I put the pure function definition of `Transformer` inside the definition of some other bigger function, the same weird output will generate.

**I wonder why the function environment causes such a big difference?**

Comment: Your "weird output" case is because you defined `Transformer` to take an argument and produce a `Function`. You didn't actually include the full output, but if you look carefully at your actual output, you'll see that it's a `Function` expression (you can either see the `&` at the end or you can look at `FullForm` and see a `Function` head. Just remove the `&` from the end of your definition.

Comment: @lericr you are right. I removed the `&` and now there is a new output which is still not desirable. Am I  using the `Evaluate` incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's due to the renaming mechanism of nested scopings.

When evaluating `Transformer2[algebra_] :=` , the local variable `algebra` needs to be evaluated in the right side, and there appears a double scoping involving local variables `algebra, $g, ...`, then the rule

```
{$g_ :> $g[n_] /; MemberQ[generators, $g]})
```

is automatically renamed as

```
{$g$_ :> $g[n$_] /; MemberQ[generators, $g]}
```

Instead, if you define

```
Transformer22[algebra_] := 
    Table[
        (rule[[1]] /. {$g_ :> $g[n_] /; MemberQ[generators, $g]}):>
            Evaluate[(rule[[2]] /. {gg_ :> gg[n] /; MemberQ[generators, gg]})],
        {rule,algebra}
    ]
```

or just the pure function you have given,
the local variable `algebra` will be replaced by its value and there is no nested scoping during evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really seem to have to do with `Function` versus `SetDelayed`, so it might warrant a separate question. Rather then debug the provided code, I'd suggest a different approach.

Whenever you have a construct like `Table[..., {i,Length[something]}]`, you would probably be better off with some sort of `Map`. But, since what you're really doing is `ReplaceAll`, you don't need to iterate explicitly at all. But again, you do want a slightly different replacement to the left hand sides than to the right hand sides. But `SubsetMap` gives us a nifty way to handle such situations. So, I'd proceed like this:

```
(* create replacement rules *)
lhsRules = Thread[generators -> (Construct[#, n_] & /@ generators)];
rhsRules = Thread[generators -> (Construct[#, n] & /@ generators)];

result = 
  RuleDelayed @@@ 
    (SubsetMap[
       ReplaceAll[rhsRules], 
       SubsetMap[ReplaceAll[lhsRules], Level[#, 1] & /@ algebra, {All, 1}], 
       {All, 2}] /. x_ ** x_ :> x^2)
```

Now, you use `1` is some places and `Id` in others, so you'll need to sort that out.

Of course, you can put this into a definition:

```
Transformer[algebra_] := ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I haven't used `SubsetMap` before. I'll implement something like this in the future code.